# How to install a custom LAF?

Tags: java, swing, packaging, look-and-feel, substance

I'm using Netbeans IDE and I want to use the Insubstantial LAF in a Java application (http://insubstantial.posterous.com/). However, I have no idea how I would go about installing it. Does anybody have experience with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put its jar in the classpath, and, in your main method, before displaying any Swing component, add the following code:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("fully.qualified.name.of.the.LookAndFeel");
```